# Jquery Fancybox callback issue

Tags: jquery, callback, fancybox-2

I seem to be having an interesting issue with callback and fancybox.  Here is the issue:  I have a fancybox that I call from multiple buttons.  The fancybox is a modal yes no box.  When the user selects yes, a callback is issued.  This works great.  The issue comes when the user selects another item, the fancybox shows and the user selects yes again.  The callback is fired twice, once for the previous item, and once for the new item.  Here is my code:

Button call to show fancybox (multiple on the page):

```
<button id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderColMain_ucSKUList_rptSkuList_ctl00_btnAdd" class="btn btnCart btnColor5" ss="oos" skuid="12345" onclick="initAddToCart(this);">Back Order</button>
```

Fancybox html:

```
<div id="backorderVerify" style="display:none;">
        <div class="inner">
            <h2>Item is not in stock!</h2>
            <div class="base">
                <div align='center'>
                    Would you like to backorder?
                </div>
                <div align="center" style="margin:20px 0 0 0;">
                    <input type="button" id="btnBOYes" value="Yes" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnBONo" value="No" />
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function backorderVerify(objAddBtn) {

    $.fancybox({
        'closeBtn': false,
        'href' : '#backorderVerify',
        'beforeShow' : function () {

            $("#btnBOYes").click(function () {
                $.fancybox.close(true);                    
                    addToCart($(objAddBtn).attr("skuid"), objAddBtn);
            });

            $("#btnBONo").click(function () {
                $.fancybox.close(true);
            });
        }

    });


}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  `<input type="button"></button>`.  `<button>` and `<input>` are two different things; you don't close one kind of tag with another totally different tag.  `input` is usually self-closed, `<input />`.  Also `align="center"` was deprecated a while ago.  Run your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I have correct the HTML in the question (a cut and paste error).  Whether or not the styling is depreciated is not the point.

Comment: No, it's not the point of your question, but it's totally acceptable to call out these kinds of coding errors within comments.  SO is a place for learning (even if you can't appreciate it) for also the reader.

Comment: Are you repeating `id="btnBOYes"` and `id="btnBONo"` elsewhere on the page? ID's must be unique, otherwise you have [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) which may cause other problems... and that's the point.

Comment: Yes, both buttons are completely unique on the page.

Comment: How do you call the function `backorderVerify()`?

Comment: It seems like the callback inside `backorderVerify()` function is not properly closed.... you are closing the `beforeShow` callback before you bind the `click` to the `#btnBONo` selector, unless is another copy/paste error.

Comment: JFK - The function is called through another js method that determines if the item is out of stock.  I stepped through and made sure that everything was closed properly.  It's almost like fancybox is attaching each iteration to the DOM but not removing it after close, so every time the yes button is clicked, it moves through each instance and fires the click event.

Comment: Why you don't edit your question with your "properly closed" code (the one you have is not), otherwise is misleading, unless you don't need help any longer.

Comment: Sorry about that.  It has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fliim actually had the right idea.  The before show was being bound each time the fancybox was called.  Therefore, it was being called for each bound item.  I ended up pulling the Yes/No click events out of the fancybox call, and made each their own method that would be called by the buttons.  Thanks for everyone's help on this.

Answer (score -1):

I think your shouldnt define your click handle in the beforeShow event. Maybe every time the event happend, he define one more time.

Comment: could you please tell me why you downgrade me?

Comment: Please provide a grammatically correct solution along with the relevant code.

Comment: you gave me -1 because I suggest a solution without giving any code ?

Comment: Did I say I gave you -1?  I'm suggesting that you fix your spelling, grammar and include some code so your answer makes sense.